# load HTML\PHP pages into another Page's div

Tags: php, css, html

lets say i have two pages `links.html` & `contents.php`... first page contains only html code while the second page contains some **HTML + PHP code**....

now i ant to create a page `index.php` with two DIVs in which i want to show\load the above two pages...

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="links" class="myCustom1">
    <!--here will be the links.html page-->
    </div>

    <div id="contents" class="myCustom2">
    <!--here will be the contents.php page-->
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

**HOW TO DO IT**

Comment: Why do you vote people down if you don't know the answer somebody gives is wrong. I would not help you just because you will vote me down if I misunderstood your question or you misunderstood my answer. Just my 2 cents. BTW, include/require is the way to go!

Comment: It's a straight forward beginner question, there's absolutely nothing wrong with this at all. People downvoting are just being .. well, there's no polite way to put it. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the include functions (require(), require_once() functions would work as well), like this:

(change links.html to links.php)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="links" class="myCustom1">
    <?php include("links.php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contents" class="myCustom2">
    <?php include("contents.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

I set it to links.html which is your filename but if it's in a subdirectory you need to specify it as well.

eg:

```
include("subfolder/links.html");
```

Comment: that's not possible, I have been using include for years. it is used to include other files into php files. Are you sure you created a php file named index.php like you mentioned? and it's in that file you want to show the content of those 2 external files?

Comment: yes... and i know how the paths work.... i have been googling it... it something to with innerhtml

Comment: Have you tried to rename the links.html to links.php to that the php gets evaluated? If you see <?php include("contents.php"); ?> in your html page, this is the case.

Comment: the .php file has been loaded but not the .html file

Comment: @krike: my vote is locked in.. edit your answer... i need to vote up

Answer (score 2):

Use the [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) function to add the content of the other files to your template.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="links" class="myCustom1">
       <?php require('links.html'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contents" class="myCustom2">
        <?php require('content.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please carefully recheck your code. It should work for sure.
Or, add more details on the problem you facing.

Answer (score 0):

use the code people posted above, but make links.html a php file..

OR if you really dont want to do this you can tell the PHP engine to parse HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to double check that the page you're loading (including or requiring) doesn't have the html head tags at the top of them.

I couldn't figure out why when I included a file, the page (which works without the include) wouldn't load. I viewed the source from my browser and found the html and head tags from the loaded page down at the point where I had included that file.