# load HTML pages into another Page's div WITHOUT php or code (replacing iframes)

Tags: html, content-management-system

I found answers about how to do this *WITH* php (example: [load HTML\PHP pages into another Page's div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3573113/463994)).

However, I need to be able to do this in a CKEditor and I ***don't*** have the ability to include PHP code (or javascript or any other code).

Here's the existing iframe I wish to replace with divs (if possible):

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/page1/2/3.html" frameborder="0" height="400" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I appreciate any ideas... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try AJAX to load the content?

//Its a javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $('#15').click(function()
                    {
                        $(".box").load('content8.html');
                    });

                    $('#16').click(function()
                    {
                        $(".box").load('edit.html');
                    });

            </script>
```

// For Displaying the content, create a seperate DIV:

```
            <div class="box effect8" >

            "The Ajax content loaded inside this div"       
            </div>
```

Comment: Notice that I said, "I need to be able to do this in a CKEditor and I don't have the ability to include PHP code." I cannot enter javascript either. It's code, just like php code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is simply not possible. However. what you can do is apply styles to your `iframe` to make it work more like a `div`. An `iframe` is inline, and a `div` is `block`. You can make your `iframe` block so that it behaves like a `div`.

Without CSS:

```
<iframe style="display:block" src="http://www.example.com/page1/2/3.html" frameborder="0" height="400" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
```

With CSS:

```
iframe
{
    display: block;
}
```